# Management agent "MOSSAD-HRDomain" failed on run profile "DS_DELTAIMPORT" because the server encountered errors

Tags: user-profile-service

SharePoint 2010 User Profile Service not able to import data from AD and this issue facing from last 2 days previously it was working without any issue.
In Event viewer getting below error:

> "The management agent "MOSSAD-HR Domain" failed on run profile
>   "DS_DELTAIMPORT" because the server encountered errors." (Source:
>   FIMSynchronizationService, Task: Management Agent Run Profile, Event
>   Id: 6056) Some more event id: 6060 and 6110

In Synchronization Service Manager  console the Status showing stopped-server

Also 2 days ago FIM Synchronization Service was stopped in service console and in order to start it I had to create miiskeys-1.bin file because it was giving error while starting that id and password issue and I confirmed that no one made any account related change in SharePoint 2010 farm.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure below two things

1. Enough disk space available in Sync DB
2. FIM Service and FIM sync Service are running with appropriate user accounts